# Collapse columns before aggregating by count

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have what I imagine is a very simple question, but I simply cannot figure it out after a good deal of board searching/reading tutorials.

I have a df with name entries in columns 5 through 12 that are all of one type. They are name strings (see below for example). All I would like to do is use the aggregate or ddply (or another, if easier...) function to collapse those columns and then return the count of each unique entry.

```
ID | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 
Row 1: 278 | John | Tim | Mike
Row 2: 279 | Tim | Steve | John
Row 3: 280 | Tim | Doug | Dave
```

So ideally I'd get:

```
 Tim | 3 
 John | 2
 Mike | 1 
 etc. | 1
```

I know how this works for one column:

```
counts=aggregate(numeric(nrow(df)), df[c(4)], length)
```

But when I use a similar line for multiple columns, it returns the unique combinations of the seven columns, instead of an nx2 vector with the aggregated unique entries and total sums.

```
counts2=aggregate(numeric(nrow(df)),df[c(5:12)],FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use `unlist` and `table`?

Comment: unlist works too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not as up to speed on the *new* packages that Hadley has come up with, but here's how I'd solve the problem using `reshape2` package. The idea (same as above) is to collapse the columns into one column and then summarize that data:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(data = melt(foo, id.vars = "id"), value ~ .)
#---
  value .
1  Dave 1
2  Doug 1
3  John 2
4  Mike 1
5 Steve 1
6   Tim 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
foo <- data.frame(id = 278:280,
                  Name1 = c("John", "Tim", "Mike"),
                  Name2 = c("Tim", "Steve", "John"),
                  Name3 = c("Tim", "Doug", "Dave"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo %>%
    gather(var, names, -id) %>%
    count(names)

#  names n
#1  Dave 1
#2  Doug 1
#3  John 2
#4  Mike 1
#5 Steve 1
#6   Tim 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your data:

```
txt <- "ID | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 
Row 1: 278 | John | Tim | Mike
Row 2: 279 | Tim | Steve | John
Row 3: 280 | Tim | Doug | Dave "
dat <- read.csv(text = txt, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

You can use the `as.data.frame` table method on the unlisted columns.

```
u <- unlist(dat[-1])
as.data.frame(table(levels(u)[u]))
#    Var1 Freq
# 1  Dave    1
# 2  Doug    1
# 3  John    2
# 4  Mike    1
# 5 Steve    1
# 6   Tim    3
```